# (Javascript-HTML) put formulary variable inside a TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redmine, redmine-plugins

I build this formulary using appends in a div.

```
  var ip = $('#issue_custom_field_values_87').parent();

$('#issue_status_id').closest(".splitcontent").after($('<div id="POPACC" class="splitcontent">')); 
$('#POPACC').css("background-color","#FAFCAF");
$('#POPACC').append($("<p><h3>2.ACCIONES</h3><hr style='background-color: black; height:2px'></p>"));
$('#POPACC').append($('<div id="POPAQL" class="splitcontentleft">'));
$('#POPACC').append($('<div id="POPAQR" class="splitcontentright">'));
$('#POPAQL').append(ip);
```

it works.

now i need build html table

```
var ip = $('#issue_custom_field_values_87').parent();

$('#issue_status_id').closest(".splitcontent").after($('<div id="tablePrint"></div>'));  
var myTable= "<table><tr><td></td><td>"+ip+"</td>;    
myTable+="</tr>";
myTable+="</table>";

document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
```

The variable ip returns object Object.

What am I doing wrong? Thank You!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: `var myTable= "<table><tr><td></td><td>"+ip.html()+"</td>; `

Comment: thanks it works but this make a duplicate of the label(ip) , i need get the label already in the form and put him inside the td , like this $('#issue_status_id').closest(".splitcontent").after($('<div id="POPACC" class="splitcontent">'));     $('#POPAQL').append(ip);

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution , ty!

```
$('#issue_status_id').closest(".splitcontent").after($('<div id="tablePrint"></div>'));  
  var myTable= "<table border='1'><tr><td>HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH</td><td><div id='addDataHere'></td>";    
  myTable+="</tr>";
  myTable+="</table>";


  document.getElementById('tablePrint').innerHTML = myTable;
  $('#addDataHere').append(ip);
```